# Error when exporting a zip file: "The entry name must be non-null and non-empty"

Tags: c#, asp.net

`Ionic.Zip.AddFile` gives an error:

> "The entry name must be non-null and non-empty"

My code:

```
zip.AddFile(filePath, File path);
```

or

```
zip.AddFile(filePath,"")

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=CallRecording" + DateTime.Now);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

both code getting same error.

Comment: what value does `filePath` have?

Comment: I have sorted out the issue, In my filepath 1 folder is missing . Thanks all, for your support

Answer (score 0):

The "non-null and non empty" error means that you're trying to add a file that has either a null value or "" as the filename.

You might find that one of the values in the list is either empty or null.

Comment: i already tried this https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/203952  but zip.AddFile(filePath, Filepath); filepath not empty